# Firefox auto deletes xpi from Profiles folder on load

Tags: firefox, visual-c++, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, browser-extension

I created a Firefox add-on.

Now when I place it into the current Profiles folder manually and load the browser, it prompts for installation.
But when I copy the .xpi file to the current Profiles folder using a VC++ executable and then reload the browser, it auto-deletes the .xpi file.

Please guide where this is going wrong. I believe copying via the VC++ executable is raising some issue.

Here's the code for the same :

```
FILE* pnReadFile = fopen(spnDirPtr->d_name, "r");

if (pnReadFile)
{
    char strDestFileName[MAX] = { 0 };                                  
    sprintf(strDestFileName, "%s\%s", arDestPath, xpi);

    FILE* pnWriteFile = fopen(strDestFileName, "w");    /*File Pointer to write in file*/

    if (pnWriteFile)
    {
        char buffer[MAX] = { 0 };    /*Buffer to store files content*/

        while (fgets(buffer, MAX, pnReadFile))
        {
            fputs(buffer, pnWriteFile);
        }
        fclose(pnWriteFile);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Unable to open file %s", strDestFileName);
    }
    fclose(pnReadFile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i was able to figure out the same. The file I/O methods did not copy the xpi completely because of which the xpi went corrupt and thus getting automatically deleted on firefox load. I used system() copy command and was able to accomplish the same suuccessfully.

Comment: Thanks for this knowledge share!